# How to get the group members fro Google Group

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-groups

I am triying to create a service to list all groups from my domain and members inside the group. I am able to print the group  names with the below code , Can anyone suggest on how to get the group members ?

```
 Directory.Groups.List request = directory.groups().list();
    request.setDomain("mydomain.com");

    //request.setQuery("name:'manu'");
    com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Groups currentPage = request.execute();

    List<com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Group> allGroups = new ArrayList<com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Group>();


    System.out.println("Group size--"+currentPage.getGroups().size());
     for (int i = 0; i < currentPage.getGroups().size()-1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name----"+currentPage.getGroups().get(i).getName());
        System.out.println("Name----"+currentPage.getGroups().get(i).getDirectMembersCount());

     }
```

Comment: To get the list of members in group, send request to Members.list https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list include groupkey(which identifies the group).

Comment: Follow this link:

[The question on this link addresses the solution to list members of a group with pagination, to list all members, without any limit.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243902/members-list-in-google-admin-sdk-directory-api-java/31260400#31260400