# How to use Streams instead of do while loop?

Tags: java, java-stream, google-directory-api

How to avoid imperative loops and use the Java's Streaming API for the below mentioned implementation for the google directory API?

```
List<GroupMember> groupMemberList = new ArrayList<>();
Directory.Members.List listRequest = getDirectoryApi().members().list(groupEmailAddress);
Members members;
do {
    members = listRequest.execute();
    members.getMembers().forEach(member -> groupMemberList.add(new
        GroupMember(member.getId(), member.getEmail())));
} while (null != members.getNextPageToken());
return groupMemberList;
```

Comment: Streams are not a good usecase for pagination

Comment: Avoiding imperative loops is not a sensible goal.  The goal should be to maximize readability ... and some tasks are not more readable (or efficient) if you try to shoe-horn them into a solution using the Stream's API.  Just because you have bought a new hammer doesn't mean you should use it for *all* of your woodworking tasks.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about this ... but shouldn't your code be using `setNextPageToken()` to advance to the next page?   As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/31260400/139985 ?

Comment: @StephenC You are right on this. Thanks for pointing that out.